# Adjusted clean function in form template does not pass errors to the form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-validation

I have a custom search form with 3 input fields (last_name, first_name and client_id) for searching a client and if successful redirect to client page or show a list of multiple clients if the client is not unique.

Basic functionality:

- either use one or both name fields OR the client_id field for retrieving client(s) information (via AJAX call from database)
- if client_id field is used: the result is always unique and redirection to page of the client
- if name fields are used: the result can be unique (followed by redirection to the page of the client) or can be a list of clients (show a modal with list of the clients so we can choose one and redirect)

The form works with the AJAX call, but the error handling does not work. The errors are not shown in the html form, except for the error.message.

form in html:

```html
<form class="p-3" id="client_selection">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {% if form.non_field_errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
                    {{ error }}
                {% endfor %}
        </div>
        {% endif %}

        <div class="form-group row justify-content-md-center">
            <label for="last_name" class="col-2 col-form-label text-left">Name:</label>
                <div class="col-4">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name" placeholder="Eingabe des Namen"> 
        </div>
                {{ form.last_name.errors }}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row justify-content-md-center"> 
        <label for="first_name" class="col-2 col-form-label text-left">Vorname:</label>
        <div class="col-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" placeholder="Eingabe des Vornamen"> 
        </div>
                {{ form.first_name.errors }}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row justify-content-md-center">
            <div class="col-2">
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <span>ODER</span>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row justify-content-md-center">
            <label for="client_id" class="col-2 col-form-label text-left">Kunden ID:</label>
                <div class="col-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="client_id" placeholder="Eingabe der Kunden ID" />
                </div>
                {{ form.client_id.errors }}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row justify-content-md-center">
            <div class="col-2">
            </div>
                <div class="form-text text-danger col-4" id="form-error">
                </div>
        </div>

    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10"></div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <input class="btn mt-3 btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="suchen &gt;">
        </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

AJAX call in the html file:

```
    var clientSearchUrl = "{% url 'validate-client' %}";

    function show_result_list(list) {
        list.forEach(element => {
            console.log('to be created: show modal with the clients information in a list')
            console.log(element['client_id'])
            console.log(element['client_last_name'])
            console.log(element['client_first_name'])
        });
    }

    $('#client_selection').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: clientSearchUrl,
            data: {
                client_id: $('#client_id').val(),
                last_name: $('#last_name').val(),
                first_name: $('#first_name').val(),
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.list) {
                    show_result_list(data.list)
                } else {
                    console.log(data.client_id)
                    window.location.href = "/client-cockpit/" + data.client_id + "/";
                }

            },
            error: function (error) {

                console.log(error);
                $("#form-error").html(error.responseJSON['message']);
                if (error.responseJSON['client_id']) {
                    $("#client_id").addClass('is-invalid');
                }
                if (error.responseJSON['last_name']) {
                    $("#last_name").addClass('is-invalid');
                }
                if (error.responseJSON['first_name']) {
                    $("#first_name").addClass('is-invalid');
                }



            }
        })

    })
```

ValidateClient class in views.py:

```py
class ValidateClient(APIView):
    authentication_classes = ()
    permission_classes = ()

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = SelectClient(request.data)

        if form.is_valid():
        #Check if mutliple clients or a single client is in response
            if "list" in form.cleaned_data.keys():
                return Response({"list": form.cleaned_data["list"]})
            else:
                return Response({"client_id": form.cleaned_data["client_id"]})
        else:
        #Check if data even exists
            if (
                form.data["client_id"]
                or form.data["last_name"]
                or form.data["first_name"]
            ):
                error = {}
                if form.data["client_id"]:
                    error["client_id"] = form.data["client_id"]
                if form.data["last_name"]:
                    error["last_name"] = form.data["last_name"]
                if form.data["first_name"]:
                    error["first_name"] = form.data["first_name"]
                error["message"] = form.non_field_errors()
            else:
                error = {"message": "Please enter any value in the form."}
            return Response(error, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

SelectClient form class in forms.py:

```py
class SelectClient(forms.Form):
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=False)
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=False)
    client_id = forms.CharField(required=False)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(SelectClient, self).clean()  # Get the cleaned data from default clean, returns cleaned_data
        field_client_id = cleaned_data.get("client_id")
        field_last_name = cleaned_data.get("last_name")
        field_first_name = cleaned_data.get("first_name")

        if field_client_id and (field_last_name or field_first_name):
            raise ValidationError(
                _("Either client_id or name fields."),
                code="toomany",
            )

        if not field_client_id and (field_last_name and field_first_name):
            # Name search
            if Client.objects.filter(
                client_last_name=field_last_name, client_first_name=field_first_name
            ).exists():
                print("Success!")
                if Client.objects.filter(client_last_name=field_last_name, client_first_name=field_first_name).count() == 1:
                    cleaned_data["client_id"] = Client.objects.get(
                        client_last_name=field_last_name, client_first_name=field_first_name
                    ).client_id
                else:
                    cleaned_data["list"] = list(
                        Client.objects.filter(client_last_name=field_last_name, client_first_name=field_first_name).values(
                            "client_id", "client_last_name", "client_first_name"
                        )
                    )
            else:
                print("No such client!")
                self.add_error("last_name", "Nachname nicht gefunden!")
                self.add_error("first_name", "Vorname nicht gefunden!")
                raise ValidationError(_("Kunde wurde nicht gefunden."), code="noclient")

        elif field_last_name:
            if Client.objects.filter(client_last_name=field_last_name).exists():
                print("Success!")
                if Client.objects.filter(client_last_name=field_last_name).count() == 1:
                    cleaned_data["client_id"] = Client.objects.get(
                        client_last_name=field_last_name
                    ).client_id
                else:
                    cleaned_data["list"] = list(
                        Client.objects.filter(client_last_name=field_last_name).values(
                            "client_id", "client_last_name", "client_first_name"
                        )
                    )

            else:
                print("No such client!")
                self.add_error("last_name", "Name nicht gefunden!")
                raise ValidationError(_("Kunde wurde nicht gefunden."), code="noclient")

        elif field_first_name:
            if Client.objects.filter(client_first_name=field_first_name).exists():
                print("Success!")
                if Client.objects.filter(client_first_name=field_first_name).count() == 1:
                    cleaned_data["client_id"] = Client.objects.get(
                        client_first_name=field_first_name
                    ).client_id
                else:
                    cleaned_data["list"] = list(
                        Client.objects.filter(client_first_name=field_first_name).values(
                            "client_id", "client_last_name", "client_first_name"
                        )
                    )
            else:
                print("No such client!")
                self.add_error("first_name", "Vorname nicht gefunden!")
                raise ValidationError(_("Kunde wurde nicht gefunden."), code="noclient")
        else:
            # Client ID search
            if Client.objects.filter(client_id=field_client_id).exists():
                print("Success!")

            else:
                print("No such client!")
                self.add_error("client_id", "Kunden ID nicht gefunden!")
                raise ValidationError(
                    _("Ungültige Kunden ID - kein solcher Kunde vorhanden!"),
                    code="noclient",
                )

        return cleaned_data
```

The errors for specific fields are not passed to the AJAX response. And the code is quite nasty I think. What is the proper way of handling such a situation?

Comment: Your ajax `error` function doesn't display the errors, except for the 'message' one. For the others, all it does it change the class attribute of the corresponding input fields. Why do you expect the errors to show up?

Comment: Also why you assign the form.data['client_id'] to the error is not clear, if you want to have the actual error message you should assign `form['client_id'].errors` (the errors are on the `BoundField`)

Comment: Hint: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors.as_data

Comment: @dirkgroten because the errors are linked in the form by {{ form.last_name.errors }} as usual. The problem is the errors are not saved there.

Comment: But you're submitting the form via ajax, so there's not template being rendered at all. The `{{ form.last_name.errors }}` is rendered the first time you load your page. When you submit your form using ajax, your view just returns json. Your HTML page sits in the browser so your script needs to change the HTML if you want to show anything to the user.

Comment: @dirkgroten I see, valid point. I changed the assigned error value as you suggested. Therefore the only thing left to do is to display it after the ajax call?

Comment: yes, as you do for your #form-error div, you need to change  the html of the other error divs.